# Uso do ACL no CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

Após pesquisar bastante, não achei uma resposta satisfatória. Gostaria da opinião e/ou dica de vocês quanto ao uso do ACL no CakePHP.

Já vi alguns plugins que "ajudam" nessa questão, mas não achei nenhum dinâmico o bastante.

Alguns dizem que fazer "na mão" é melhor, outros dizem que usar plugin é melhor, enfim, o ACL não é complexo, porém para um sistema com dezenas de grupos e milhares de usuários é complicado organizar as coisas. Por isso procuro um plugin que realmente torne essa tarefa mais prática e dinâmica, ou se necessário farei um para isso, mas antes de colocar a mão na massa, gostaria da opinião de vocês.

Comment: A maioria dos tutoriais de ACL do Cakephp que vejo, realmente, são feitos na mão.

Answer (score 0):

Então cara, realmente as ferramentas mais automáticas para uso/gerência do Acl estão em falta.
Eu trabalho com Acl nos meus projetos, e as únicas ferramentas que eu utilizo para são o [Cake Acl Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/acl-shell.html) (nativo do framework) e o plugin [AclExtras](https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/) que não recebe nenhuma atualização desde 2013.

Ainda não estou totalmente inteirado no Acl da versão 3.x mas pelo que vi não houve muitas mudanças.